# How to invoke method to print?

Tags: java, methods, invoke

https://its.hvcc.edu/jojo/?p=297

Doing this assignment I need the results of the method to print but I cant figure out how to invoke them.

```
public static int numWhitespace(String s) {

    int count = 0,x;
    for(x = 0; x<s.length();x++)
      if(Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(x)))
         count++;
    return count;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string for character classification: (EOF to end):");
    while (kb.hasNext()){
       String input = kb.nextLine();
       System.out.println("inputLine = "+ input +"");

       System.out.println("inputLine is "+ input.length() +" characters long and contains the following:");

       System.out.println(); //Where i want all the other stuff

       System.out.println("Enter a string for character classification: (EOF to end):");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `numWhitespace()` method like this:

```
System.out.println("whitespaces = " + numWhitespace(input));
```

or save it in a variable first:

```
int whitespaces = numWhitespace(input);
System.out.println("whitespaces = " + whitespaces);
```